# Visualforce capabilities Winter 13 release

Tags: visualforce

I would like to know if the Winter 13 Visualforce capabilities will allow the following:

Place a multi line graph above a tabular graph and align them according to date ie. the date would be the linking factor.  Both graphs draw information from various data files and are indexed according to date.

OR

Would I have to resort to other apps to create this graphic in Salesforce and display using canvas?

For an example of what I mean: [image: http://www.drogerie-zier.ch/greg/GraphEG1SFa.jpg]

---

Thanks joshbirk.

The question I need answered is:

Can I place 2 graphs, 1 above the other, with two different formats, sharing different databases but aligning them (the graphs) by date?

If Not

What can I use to make sure Salesforce users can add my charts to their dashboard seamlessly and change their filter criteria?

Or does jqPlot feed into Visualforce page layouts and can this be done using more than one graph on one page?

It might be a bit vague but the link I posted previously will clearly show what I`m trying to achieve.

Thanks again for the response and look forward to more.

Comment: I have removed your sig. You can add one to your private page http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/856/greg that's what most do.

Answer (score 4):

There are scatter charts in Winter 13 w/ Visualforce Charting:
http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/10/visualforce-charting-for-all.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+SforceBlog+%28Force.com+Blog%29

If that does not work for you, I would recommend looking at something like jqPlot to create custom graphs.